# Updating button text in Rails with ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've looked at a lot of other SO questions but can't seem to get this working. After clicking "complete" I want the button to update to "un-complete" (example text only). The actual action goes through fine (via ajax) but I can't get the button to refresh. I suspect it's the way the js is. Any advice is appreciated.

It's a link_to now. Will be button_to though.

lessons_controller.rb

```
  def toggle_complete  
    @complete = Lesson.find(params[:id])  
    @complete.progress(current_user).toggle!(:completed)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @complete.save
        format.html { redirect_to @complete, notice: "'completed' updated" }
        format.js
      else
        redirect_to @complete, notice: "Not updated"
      end 
    end
  end
```

complete_button partial (on the lesson#show page)

```
<% if user_signed_in? && @lesson.progress(current_user).present? %>
    <div class="toggle-complete">
        <%= link_to complete_link_text(@lesson.progress(current_user)),   
                    toggle_complete_lesson_path(@lesson),   
                    :remote => true, class: "complete-link-single "
                     %>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <div class="complete-lesson">
        <%= link_to 'Complete', create_progress_lesson_path, :method => 'post', remote: true %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

lesson_helper (decides 'complete' or 'un-complete' depending on attribute)

```
def complete_link_text(completable)
    if completable.present?  
    completable.completed? ? 'Un-complete' : 'Complete'
  else
    'Un-complete'
  end
end
```

toggle_complete.js.erb

```
$('.complete-link-single').html('<%= complete_link_text(@lesson.progress(current_user)) %>');
```

Comment: Your JQuery refers to `complete-link-single`, but you have `complete_link_single` (underscores) in your `link_to`.

Comment: Ahh thank you for that, but still, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you may have to add coffeescript code like this:

```
$ ->
  $(".complete-link-single").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
   $('.abc').text('Un-complete')
```

Assuming your link has a class 'abc' like this

```
<%= link_to 'Complete', create_progress_lesson_path, :method => 'post', remote: true, :class=>'abc' %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still not working, but I'll have a read through the guide link.